# How to cast string enum to another enum with the same keys?

Tags: typescript

Given by these 2 string enums with always the same keys:

```js
enum StatusEnum {
    SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS',
    ERROR = 'ERROR',
    WARN = 'WARN',
    DEBUG = 'DEBUG',
}

enum RawStatusEnum {
    SUCCESS = 'Success',
    ERROR = 'Error',
    WARN = 'Warn',
    DEBUG = 'Debug',
}
```

I want to cast value of enum `RawStatusEnum` to value of enum `StatusEnum`, that is:

```
const rawEnumValue = RawStatusEnum.ERROR // RawStatusEnum
const normalEnumValue = cast(rawEnumValue) // StatusEnum
```

But I have problems with typings and ... I've learnt about reverse mapping in typescript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214527/converting-one-enum-to-another-in-javascript), but reverse mapping works only for numeric enums. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you *need* to use enums?  Could you use [`const` asserted objects instead](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)?

Comment: not sure and do not know the actual difference, but if you think it can solve the issue -- I will vote your answer and perhaps use your solution. Of course, I prefer just enums and haven't heard yet about what you suggest

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJqe6m) meet your needs?  It's a little weird to play with enums this way, so I don't know that I really recommend it, but the approach here is to programmatically generate the reverse enum for `RawStatusEnum` and then do a nested lookup.  If it meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining it; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, I think yes, it does. Please, post your answer -- I'll accept it. And if you don't mind I'd like to learn about another better approach suggested by you (I mean using const enums or smth else), please

Comment: I think it would take me too far afield to try refactoring your code to something I'd recommend.  I personally dislike enums for a number of reasons (I can go into these if necessary) but synthesizing a reverse map for string enums is straightforward enough that I think it's probably reasonable if you're otherwise happy with enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, [string `enums`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) don't automatically get a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), so getting the key from a value isn't as simple as a lookup.

However, it's fairly straightforward to write a helper function to generate a reverse mapping for a string enum.  But the compiler can't verify that it's implemented properly so you'll need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  For example:

```
const reverseStringEnum = <T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(e: T) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(e).map(([k, v]) => [v, k])) as 
   { [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K };
```

It uses the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) methods to split the enum object into key-value pairs and then put it back together with the keys and values swapped.  The input object type is `T`, and the output object type is `{[K in keyof T as T[K]]: K}`, which uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to swap the key and value types also.

Let's test it out on `RawStatusEnum`:

```
const RawStatusReverseEnum = reverseStringEnum(RawStatusEnum);
/* const RawStatusReverseEnum: {
    readonly Success: "SUCCESS";
    readonly Error: "ERROR";
    readonly Warn: "WARN";
    readonly Debug: "DEBUG";
} */
```

Looks good.  And now we can "cast" a `RawStatusEnum` to a `StatusEnum` by doing a pair of lookups.  We lookup the key in `RawStatusReverseEnum` and then use the key to lookup the value in `StatusEnum`:

```
const castRawToNormal = <T extends RawStatusEnum>(t: T) =>
  StatusEnum[RawStatusReverseEnum[t]];
```

Let's use it:

```
const rawEnumValue = RawStatusEnum.ERROR // RawStatusEnum

const normalEnumValue = castRawToNormal(rawEnumValue);
// const normalEnumValue: StatusEnum.ERROR

console.log(normalEnumValue); // "ERROR"
```

Looks good.  The compiler even knows that `normalEnumValue` will be of type `StatusEnum.ERROR`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzgUXNA3gWAFBSwCqAwiWjDFALxQDkMp5ldANPoWgEpcDyXNetz5c2HKAHUAglwBygutLliCUACJoAQkQDiCjdp0qAvvnyhIULggDu8JKgyXcqxmQpVaDMAGMfwFBQVTh5+BTQAJwiAewjgyRl5LwkECJB4g119YAAjMABzEzM8H2iQFDgoCOAAN2AIlGB4CIBLEHynaFoAHgAVKGAADzhQABMUK2BSiNHugGtgAE9ogDMoXtYoCtb2gD5dgApgAC51gEoaXfFeHIArKbgAOhWYiAw4VoCDm-ufJ9APi0vsAzo8IAgAA4HA4AbTmmxqAF0LtRdlAYTVNnNkRcEBMsOiANJQNpQBbLNb9PHrGGExGI07E4wAbmKpXKlWsdkQyBQXFq9UanUE1TqDSagPanQOXPsvM6Z1ZeAA9AAqKDsipWWxy1D8sVCzCnFyEQjVBCjMoAG0WsF8-kCpwARG5mDAnUrTVVgBbrbbIjEIs7hPwPeIzT7LSAbZJUiBnUpZGHVBHfdHbWpcgVnZkdMnjFBVcq2WUtT48XAub1orJYuCrYI+gNhmMJrKeY5MIc4Kdeiirq4O+hMDD2w4+QLxZ0YXB6UrivhNZUIrZOgA1BBWsDAQRj+WYR4hgTK5Xa7njzqL0uVEB1zfrzfbwTlipVmt3q0HFc2B9bkFKk8NWvKBbwietf23U5dWHSBD1CLgr3KaIrWAR4rWifIDlA8DMA3P9FSgQCnSPJ0FzwIA)